# Nim in Haskell : recursive function for creating board

Tags: haskell, recursion

I'm creating a game called nim using haskell. To summarize the game short:
By calling nim followed by a number up to to 9 I create the board for the game:

```
>> nim 3
```

```
1 *
2 * *
3 * * *
  1 2 3
```

This is working as it should. The game goes as follows: You can remove any number of stars fro any row, but you have to remove at least 1 star. You cannot remove stars from row 1 and 2 in the same turn. Person to remove last star wins.

Okay, so the game plays as it should, but a problem occurs when I'm printing the board after each turn.

Let's say I have the board above, and give input to remove 1 1 (remove 1 star from row 1)

This is what I get:

```
0 
2 * *
3 * * *
  1 2 3
```

The 0 should still be 1.

These are my functions responsible for printing the board
`putRow` takes in the row number and the number of stars. These two arguments are the same but I had no luck with changing the function to only accept 1.

`putBoard` takes in the list that represents the board for the game. putBoard [1,2,3] creates the board from the game above. I runs putStr in the first element and then recursively calls putRow in the remainder of the list.

```
putRow :: Int -> Int -> IO ()
putRow row num = do putStr (show row)
                    putStr " "
                    putStrLn (concat (replicate num "* "))

putBoard :: Board -> IO ()
putBoard (x:xs) =    putRow x x >> putBoard xs
putBoard [] = putStr " 1 2 3"
```

`putBoard []` is going to be replaced later to create column numbers under the board, but thats for later. For now its just a string that only works with game with boardsize 3.

This is the function that handles moves when row and number of stars is specified

```
move :: Board -> Int -> Int -> Board
move board row num = [update r n | (r, n) <- zip [1..] board]
   where update r n = if r == row then (n - num) else n
```

Comment: I am new to haskell and currently working on creating a similar game to this. I have tried to run your code but how do I run the move function? And what is the type of the Board?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function `putRow` takes two arguments: the row number `row`, and the number of stars in that row `num`.

When you call that function from `putBoard`, you're passing the same `x` for both `row` and `num`

```
putRow x x
```

So it's no wonder that the number printed to the left matches the number of stars!

What you need to do is pass `x` (which is the number of stars) for `num`, but pass the actual index of the row for `row`:

```
putRow idx x
```

But where to get the `idx`? Well, let's see: the first time you call `putBoard`, `idx` would be `1`. And then every time you call `putBoard` recursively - that would be printing the next row, so `idx` should get incremented by one. Let's write that down:

```
putBoard :: Int -> Board -> IO ()
putBoard idx (x:xs) = putRow idx x >> putBoard (idx+1) xs
putBoard idx [] = putStr " 1 2 3"
```

But now whoever calls `putBoard` has to provide the initial `1`:

```
putBoard 1 board
```

That's a bit inconvenient, so you can wrap that up in an inner function like this:

```
putBoard :: Board -> IO ()
putBoard = go 1
  where
    go idx (x:xs) = putRow idx x >> go (idx+1) xs
    go idx [] = putStr " 1 2 3"
```